# searching an nfs-mounted volume

Tags: search, nfs

Does anyone know of a GUI way to search  mounted network volume without using Spotlight? We use a cluster roughly 80TB and need a client-side way of searching for files without indexing the entire thing every two seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out [EasyFind](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html) to see if it solves your problem. My shop has been using it to search SMB network volumes.

Comment: Thanks very much! Works like a charm and is surprisingly fast...!